# In Emacs, How do I configure to delete matching bracket just pressing delete key?

Tags: emacs, editor, spacemacs

I'm currently using Emacs(Spacemacs) in coding.

Spacemacs are using smartparens as a plugin, so close brackets are automatically inserted when I write open brackets.

But, when I delete open brackets using delete button, the close brackets remain there.

Other editor, like Atom or Sublime text, the matching bracket is automatically deleted when I delete open bracket, just pressing delete key. How do I configure this feature in Emacs?

Here are the examples.

Emacs:

[image: emacs]

Atom:

[image: atom]

Thank you for your advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could install the [autopairs](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/AutoPairs) package.

After installing, you can enable it globally by having this in your .emacs

`(require 'autopair)
(autopair-global-mode 1)`

Answer (score 0):

Actually, this is because a bug explained at
[this issue.](https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs/issues/6584)

This bug occurs when I set `hungry-delete-mode`.

And, As described that issue, auto-delete works if I add this code to my .spacemacs .

```
(defadvice hungry-delete-backward (before sp-delete-pair-advice activate) (save-match-data (sp-delete-pair (ad-get-arg 0))))
```